# Best way to remove all-metal staples from NM wire?

Tags: electrical, wiring

Recently purchased an old home that has many different generations of wiring throughout it (K&T, cloth "romex", blue NM, modern NM, conduit-fed).

At various points they were fond of using all-metal staples to attach the romex runs to the studs/joists. There are times where I cannot re-run the full wire and would prefer to re-use the existing NM run (if it's in good condition), but sometimes that means removing these staples.

What's a good approach to removing them without damaging the cable?[image: romex stapled]

Comment: Note: everything is white in the picture because of mold-remediation company spraying mold-killing primer everywhere.

Comment: you could notch out a 1x1" and use a prybar/nail puller

Answer (score 7):

Options abound, but I like side cutters or tile nippers (similar to 'end cutting pliers'). With either, grab the leg of the staple where it enters the wood and pry it up. Don't ever pry against the cable.

Comment: Agreed, thsi works too! especially with a nice meaty pair (not the cheap ones from a dollar sotre wink wink)

Answer (score 2):

If those metal staples have a wider flattened section across the middle then you should be able to to use a claw hammer to remove them.

Position the claw perpendicularly to the wire and slide the slot over the back of the staple - it should grip the staple as the slot in the claw narrows so that you can then lever it out with the hammer.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I'd update the wiring. Even if it "looks good" get it to current code and the peace of mind of safe connections, and using 1 wire type etc has value on top of value.

If you just aren't going to do that:
There's various tools you can buy where one will work better than another in each situation.
Basically get a nail puller, its small and managible. Get a 2x4" or 1x4" block, or  a 1x1" and cut a slot in it so that you can fit it right over the existing wire. Then use the block as your pivot point for the pry bar to work against. Cut new blocks as needed for awkward locations.

You could also use vice-grips and twist opposingly to widen the anchored hole and pull it out. Lastly, you could use a dremmel to cleanly cut the staple off (using a cutoff disc) and use a new staple.

Comment: Yep, updating of the wiring has commenced; this is part of that effort. As with any project, there are immediate needs, and things that come second, third, or can be shored up temporarily to allow for major renovations later. Thanks for the suggestions. I like the dremmel idea a lot.